# How to put time difference value into summation equation using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, time

Here I wrote the summation equation to find the Y value according to my csv file.

Here I want to write for range 0 with time difference. When I wrote it gave me this error, `("'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer", 'occurred at index 0')`

my summation equation,

[image]

> n = time difference in between two rows

my code:

```
def y_convert(X,time):
   Y=0
  if x == 10:            
      for k in range(0,time):
         Y=np.sum(X*k)
    else:            
       for k in range(0,time):
       Y=np.sum(X*k)
return Y
```

Then convert time difference into minute and then apply this code to find y

```
df1['time_diff'] = pd.to_datetime(df1["time"])
df1['delta'] = (df1['time_diff']-df1['time_diff'].shift()).fillna(0)
df1['t'] = df1['delta'].apply(lambda x: x  / np.timedelta64(1,'m')).astype('int64') % (24*60)

X = df1['X'].astype(int)
time=df1['t'].astype(int)

Y = df1.apply(lambda x: y_convert(x.X,x.time), axis=1)
```

Then I tried to plot the graph after getting  the correct answer provided by jezrael

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(time, df1['Y'])

ax.set_xlabel
ax.set_ylabel
plt.show()
```

Plot graph:

[image]

my csv file:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need pass column `t`, not column `time`:

```
df1['t'] = df1['delta'].dt.total_seconds().div(60).astype(int)

Y = df1.apply(lambda x: y_convert(x.X,x.t), axis=1)
```

Reason is if use `range` function in time, second argument is no time, but integer.

In your solution is used:

```
range(0,'6:15:00')
```

Also seems your solution should be simlify a lot:

```
Y = df1['X'] * (df1['t'] - 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. Can you explain little bit more, I didn't get what  you mentioned by putting t?

Comment: Ya I used long code to get Y value, Your code is absolutely simply . Thank you once again.

Comment: Can you please help me to solve this problem related to this code, Heer I am trying to plot the graph with time and y value , according to the summation equation. when I plot it it is just showing only the final value. I just want to show that while summation it will increase the value step by step , then x value change it will increase or decrease like that with time. Can you give me suggestions to clear it?

Comment: I changed the plotting code here I upload the plot graph which I got using the code. Can you please help me to solve this error?

Comment: when we look at the plot graph, you can see plot lines are together and according to my csv file I have a  long data foe five days. so here all the  Y values are together  for all five days. Here when the X is coming less graph is just increasing without decreasing, According my acknowledge I think my x axis time is not properly adding while plotting with Y .

Comment: @team - agree. My ide is join date and time columns and convert to dattimes, then plot x by datetimes. Try `df['datetimes'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']+ ' ' + df['time'], dayfirst=True)` or `df['datetimes'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']+ ' ' + df['time'])`

Comment: yes yes  it worked, you saved my day. Thank you very much.